# How to show a column when the date is end of the quarter in SSRS expression?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

In a SSRS report the end date is passed through the Parameter. If the date is a end of quarter then last column should show otherwise it should be hidden.

Can anybody help me in this?

=DateAdd(DateInterval.Quarter, DateDiff(DateInterval.Quarter, CDate("1/1/1900"), Today()), CDate("1/1/1900"))

this is what i  tried

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if the end date parameter is the last day of the `current` quarter or the end of any quarter?

Comment: @AlanSchofield yes want to compare the end date parameter with end date of any quarter. if the end date is matching with any quarter then the specific column should show up in the report else it should be supressed

Comment: I've just added an answer that should do what you need

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will update after using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following:

- Your date parameter is called `EndDate`
- You want to check if the `EndDate` is the last day of a quarter

then you can do this.

```
=
DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter, Parameters!EndDate.Value)
<>
DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, Parameters!EndDate.Value))
```

Here we are just comparing the results of two expressions. The first one just gets the quarter number for the `EndDate` parameter value.

The second part is the same except this time we are getting the quarter number for the following day.

If the two numbers do not match then they are in different quarters so the `EndDate` must be the last day of the quarter.

You should be able to use the expression exactly as above in the hidden property of the column you want to hide.